# Problem with transfer of values ​in controllers in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I have login few screens and controllers in my app. First screen is screen with button and moves user to next login view with username, password field and login button. On the controller i have function onClickButton and when i have good data i request to the server with this data.

When server give me callback i have many params about user to set in label in next view.

My structure is like this

Login View -> SecondLogin View and LoginViewController -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> Table View with TableViewController

My code is

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "afterLoginView" {
        if let secondVC = segue.destination as? TabBarViewController {
            secondVC.finalName = self.username
        }
    }  
}
```

When i want transfer my data directly to tableViewController i have error

Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

I do not understand what I'm doing wrong

Comment: It would be useful to see more detail from your error. Also, where is the finalName variable located? You make it sounds like it should be part of a tableViewController, but your code says the segue destination is the TabBarViewController.

Comment: Yes code says TabBarViewController because only this working.
When i change to TableViewController i have above error

Answer (score 1):

You'll need these values in almost all view controllers. Create a singleton class to store the logged in user values like this

```
class UserDetails: NSObject, Codable {
    static let shared = UserDetails()
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    var finalName: String?
    var otherDetails: String?
}
```

Now when you receive the response from the login api, assign the values in this singleton class.

```
UserDetails.shared.finalName = "something"//Name received from server callback
```

Now you can access these values from any view controller.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print(UserDetails.shared.finalName)
    }
}
```

Comment: I was addressing the specific issue of passing the data correctly, but this is a much better design for the data handling.

Answer (score 0):

You have some work to do to get to the right view controller. Since your segue is only pointing at the `UITabBarViewController`, you should put in another `guard` or `if/let` statement to get you to the `UINavigationController`, and then another to finally get you to the `UITableViewController`, where you can actually refer to your `finalName` variable.

That would look something like:

```
if let secondVC = segue.destination as? TabBarViewController {
    if let navCon = secondVC.viewController[0] as? UINavigationController {
        if let tableVC = navCon.topViewController as? nameOfYourTableVC {
            tableVC.finalName = self.username
}
```

The code is untested, just typed off the top of my head, so please proceed with due caution. Issues such as which tab is the correct NavController would also need to be addressed.

You need to use the actual name of your tableView class in that last if/let. A generic `UITableViewController` will not include your custom variables.

Answer (score 0):

> When server give me callback i have many params about user to set in label in next view.

This is a great example of why you should keep the M in MVC. When you get a response back from the server, store the returned data in your data model. (If you don't have a data model, you should make one.) When a view controller gets some data from the user, such as a user name, it should store that in the model. There's little reason to pass raw data back and forth between view controllers directly... just make sure that all your view controllers have a reference to the model, and have them get and set values there as needed.

This kind of approach will make your code a lot more flexible. It allows view controllers to worry about what *they* need to do their job, and it gets them out of the business of caring what *other* view controllers need.

> My structure is like this
>
> Login View -> SecondLogin View and LoginViewController -> TabBarController -> NavigationController -> Table View with TableViewController

It might make more sense to load the tab bar controller and then present the login view controller(s) modally. The view controllers that are managed by the tab bar controller can all be set up to refuse to do anything useful until the data they need is present in the data model, and that lets the tab bar controller be the root view controller. That will make it easy to set the model for each of it's child view controllers when the app starts up, and the app can then present the modal login view controllers, also set up with references to the model.